Is there an API that can identify a Solana NFT token ID / mint address from the NFT title?
We are looking to retrieve the image of individual Solana NFTs in the simplest way possible, without the need for a user to connect their wallet. On EVM chains this is easy, because the token ID is typically in the title of the NFT. So if a collector owns "Amazing PFP #1234", the collector enters "1234", which we pair with the contract address, and retrieve the asset metadata by API.
However, Solana token ID / mint address is more complicated e.g. Okay Bear #2090 has a mint address of 7TENEKwBnkpENuefriGPg4hBDR4WJ2Gyfw5AhdkMA4rq, this is obviously a lot more difficult for an end user to remember  We can have them copy this address from the asset page on another platform, such as a marketplace, but this UX isn't ideal.
I am wondering if there is any Solana NFT API that could lookup part of the title (e.g. user enters just "2090") against a specific collection (e.g. Okay Bears) to identify the mint address and perform the metadata query to retrieve the image.
Any ideas or APIs that could help us achieve this?
I suspect such an API query doesn't exist as I have done some looking through docs of Simple Hash, Moralis, Magic Eden, etc, but would like to be sure before we move ahead with a less than ideal UX.
